# Using DelayedJob and RestClient in Rails 4.2.5 Jruby 2.2.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, queue, delayed-job

I'm using delayed_jobs and rest_client in my app, I created a jobs folder and a job class jobs/test_job.rb.

```
class TestJob < Struct.new(:name)
 def perform
  RestClient.get "http://name"
 end 
end
```

RestClient and DelayedJob is working fine, but when the client(http://name) is down, the delayed_job gives me error SocketError and not retrying it.

In my controller I have this.

```
Delayed::Job.enqueue TestJob.new(my_other_rails_app), :queue => "my_test"
```

Does delayed_job not requeue when an error occured?

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem, delayed job works if error occured in different database, so it was my database has the problem, Im using openedge and the error is character string is too long for last_error field, so I need to modify the gem for not saving long error or change the field character length.
delayed-job-4-1-2\lib\delayed\backend\base.rb
From:

```
def error=(error)
    @error = error
    self.last_error = "#{error.message}\n#{error.backtrace.join("\n")}" if respond_to?(:last_error=)
end
```

To:

```
def error=(error)
 @error = error
 self.last_error = "#{error.message}" if respond_to?(:last_error=)
end
```